# Business Central can't create new customers

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central

I can't create new customers in Business Central

This are my user permissions:

[image]

When I go to customers, I can't click the new button:

[image]

But in Chronus, with same permissions I can create them:

[image]

There are no extensions.

What can I check to make the new customer button available?

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign permission set **D365 CUSTOMER, EDIT**